# Flutter Web resize browser-window leads to a defunct context

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, defunct, flutter-web-browser

I made a web-app with flutter and there are bar-charts. I want to refresh them if the screen size changes. This works fine if I switch between the browser window option "shrink" and "enlarge".
But if I use the arrows to manually change th size of the window I get this error:

```
"The widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context..."
```

Does anyone knows why this appears?

Answer (score 0):

Use `flexible` as child of scaffold. Or `Container()` with height and width = `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height` and ...`width` respectively.